# jQuery play/pause jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, setinterval

What I'm trying to do is play and pause a function ie press a button to start a function press a button to pause so on. I am not entirely sure how this can be done I have tried .live() and .die() but they don't work.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ub3wk/2/)

I have the HTML below

```
<button class="play">play</button>
<button class="pause">pause</button>
<div class="divafter"></div>​
```

and the jQuery which I'm not entirely sure what .die() does but on the jsfiddle seems to speed up the interval time.

```
(function($){
  playing = function() {
window.setInterval(function() {
    $(".divafter").after("playing <br/>");
}, 500);
};
})(jQuery);
$(".play").click(function(){
    playing().live();
});
$(".pause").click(function(){
    playing().die();
});​
```

Comment: I am no idea about what live() and die() does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Ub3wk/3/)**. You need to use clearInterval() to stop setInterval().

jQuery:

```
var foo;
playing = function() {
    foo = window.setInterval(function() {
        $(".divafter").after("playing <br/>");
    }, 500);
}

$(".play").click(function() {
    playing();
});
$(".pause").click(function() {
    clearInterval(foo);
});​
```

Answer (score 3):

`live()`and `die()` have nothing to do with what you want. So forget those :)

You need to stop the interval callback you have started. Like the below [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/BPKPG/)

```
<button class="play">play</button>
<button class="pause">pause</button>
<div class="divafter"></div>
```

```
(function($){
    var interval;        
    var playing = false;
    $(".play").click(function(){
        if(playing){
            return;
        }
        playing = true;
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            $(".divafter").after("playing <br/>");
        }, 500);
    });
    $(".pause").click(function(){
        playing = false;
        clearInterval(interval);            
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Jsfiddle does not speed anything up, you just start multiple interval callbacks.

Comment: +1 for the only answer that didn't start multiple intervals if Play is clicked multiple times in a row.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to the clearInterval to simulate the pause effect.

Grab the instance of the interval like this

```
playing = setInterval(function() {
            $(".divafter").after("playing <br/>");
          }, 500);
```

And clear to pause

```
clearInterval(playing);
```

Usage on your code would be this:

```
var playstatus;
(function($){
    playing = function() {
        return setInterval(function() {
           $(".divafter").after("playing <br/>");
           }, 500);
    };

})(jQuery);

$(".play").click(function(){
    playstatus = playing();
});
$(".pause").click(function(){
   clearInterval(playstatus);
});
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/Ub3wk/4/)

Answer (score 0):

## *[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tamQ2/)*

```
$(function(){
    
    var loop;
    
    function playing() {
        loop = setInterval(function() {
            $(".divafter").after("playing <br/>");
        }, 500);
    }
        
    $(".play").click(function(){
        playing();
    });
    $(".pause").click(function(){
        clearInterval(loop);
    });

});
```

Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

**I'm not entirely sure what .die() does but on the jsfiddle seems to speed up the interval time.**

That is because this code:

```
playing().die();
```

...is equivalent to this:

```
var playingResult = playing();
playingResult.die();
```

That is, first the `playing()` function is called, which always creates another interval. Then it attempts to call a `die()` method on whatever was returned from `playing()` which is always just an interval id, i.e., a number - which doesn't have a `die()` method (and will give an error).

The same applies to `playing().live()` - so essentially every time you click either button it adds another interval which means the actual output to the screen speeds up.

What you need is to set and clear the same interval using `setInterval()` and `clearInterval()`, *or* basically leave the interval running the whole time but put a test inside its callback to test whether it is currently paused. Jacob Oettinger's answer shows nicely how to set and clear the interval *without creating duplicate intervals* if Play is pressed multiple times in a row (none of the other answers to date test for this). The other way to do it is as follows:

```
(function($){
    var playing = false,
        intervalId = setInterval(function() {
            if (!playing)
                return;
            $(".divafter").after("playing <br/>");
        }, 500);

    $(".play").click(function(){
        playing = true;
    });
    $(".pause").click(function(){
        playing = false;          
    });    
})(jQuery);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ExCKW/