# stop/start animation loop on click? jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I am making a slideshow that continuously loops through 5 images etc. I have it looping fine but the loop won't start and stop.  I was using a pause = true/false variable and adding if statements throughout the code - not very good looking or efficient (took it out of an example).  It would spoil the animations and images would go missing if the loop paused after the statements etc.

Are there any standard methods for controlling loops like this?

```
function setupSlideShow(){
    // Setup SlideShow stuff here then start the loop
    slideBoxTransition()
}

var page = 1;
function slideBoxTransition(){
    switch (settings['transition']['effect']){
        case "slide" :
            next.css({left:settings['width']+"px",top:0,display:"block"});
            current.animate({left: "-="+width+"px"}, {duration : speed, easing : easing, queue : false});
            next.animate({left: "-="+width+"px"}, {duration : speed, easing : easing, queue : false, complete : function(){
                current.css("display","none")
                slideBoxGetImage();
            }});
            break;
    }
}

function slideBoxGetImage(){
    current = $self.eq($self.index(next))
    page += 1;
    if(page < $self.length){
        next = $self.eq( $self.index(current) + 1 );
    }else{
        page = 0;
        next = $self.first();
    }
    slideBoxTimeout();
}

function slideBoxTimeout(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        slideBoxTransition();
    }, delay);
}
```

Anything would be much appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: why don't you use a global variable called: »running«, which is a boolean value, if true set next timeout, else not. On click you toogle this value and if true call the »slideBoxTimeout()«

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var interval;
function slideBoxTimeout(){
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
        slideBoxTransition();
    }, delay);
}

$(".play").click(function() {
    slideBoxTimeout();
});
$(".pause").click(function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
});
```

taken from : [jQuery play/pause jQuery function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9856084/jquery-play-pause-jquery-function)

Comment: The interval dies after passing through 2 images when I let the loop run and just zooms thru the slide with no pauses

Comment: I had to use setTimeout() in this situation Im not sure why but it has resolves many issues in my script.